# JavaScript: Is it legal to make any operator into an assignment operator?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Is it fully legal to make uncommon operators such as `<<` or `~` into assignment operators, as in `<<=` and `~=`?  This seems to work as expected in Firefox, but is it a standard feature of the language and safe to use?  I can't find documentation of it in my brief searches.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` operator has an assignment operator counterpart in `<<=`.

The `~` operator is a unary oprator, so it can't have an assignment counterpart. There is no `~=` operator (not even as an undocumented operator in Firefox).

You can find all the assignment operators in the [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators).